# How to make flightPlanCoordinates from JSON data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have some fuction in angular to draw polyline from lat and lng in my database.  I use http.get to grap JSON data. I don't know to make polyline from json data i try to parse data it work but if my JSON data more than 100 data lat and lng how to parse ?
it my JSON data

```
{"tracking":[{"latitude":"-7.9786395","longitude":"112.5617418"},{"latitude":"-7.3342266","longitude":"112.7650341"}]}
```

my JS

```
    .controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, kaka, $ionicPopup,  $http){
     $scope.tracking = function () {
                kaka.cari($scope.item.code)
                //$http.get('http://192.168.100.13:88/OMG1/web.php?tN=find&f12=123456789')
                  .success(function(data){
                  $scope.result= data;
//                  var lat = parseFloat($scope.result.latitude);
//                  var lng = parseFloat($scope.result.longitude);
                  console.log($scope.result);
                  var lat0 = parseFloat($scope.result.tracking[0].latitude);
                  var lng0 = parseFloat($scope.result.tracking[0].longitude);
                  var lat1 = parseFloat($scope.result.tracking[1].latitude);
                  var lng1 = parseFloat($scope.result.tracking[1].longitude);
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 15,
                center: {lat: lat0, lng: lng0},
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
              });

              var flightPlanCoordinates = [
                {lat: lat0, lng: lng0},
                {lat: lat1, lng: lng1}
              ];
              var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
              });

              flightPath.setMap(map);
              })
              .error(function(data){
              });

            };
    })
```

this my jason in crome debugger

```
tracking : Array(2)
  0 : Object
    latitude : "-7.9786395"
    longitude : "112.5617418"
  1 : Object
    latitude : "-7.3342266"
    longitude : "112.7650341"
```

it work if i parse one by one my json but it not good enough if i have lat and lng more than 100. can you help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control) to iterate an array and return a new array based on data from original.

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = data.tracking.map((item)=>{
    // create new object based on current item
    var coords = {
       lat: parseFloat(item.latitude),
       lng: parseFloat(item.longitude)
    };
    // return to new array
    return coords;
});
```